# ongoing notification opening existing Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I want to show a notification while a timer is running and when the user clicks the notifiaction it opens the timer activity.

```
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The problem right now is that when I start the timer and press home and then click the notification it opens the Activity with the running timer.

But when I start the timer, then open another activity (via `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`), then press home and click the notification it opens a new Activity (empty).

I thought `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);` would help (thats what I used to navigate between Activities)

im using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

for every Activity.

Comment: Please post your manifest. In general using `launchMode="singleTask"` is a really bad idea, and if you're using this for all of your activities, then this is definitely part of your problem.

Comment: sorry I meant "singleTop".

Comment: `new Intent(this, YourActivity.class)`

Comment: Whew...OK. Are any of your activities by change with transparent background? or do the use Dialog theme?

Comment: No, no transparent background. Im using a Holo AlertDialog instead of the Holo.Light one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on your activity persisting and it is unnecessary

Store the timer start time into sharedpreferences and then simply load up the start time when the activity is recreated.

If something is meant to happen after a certain time, like a countdown time, then you'll need to set up an Alarm and handle it that way.

Remember that activities are just UI. Don't trust an activity to be doing anything when the user isn't looking at it.

Comment: I'm using countdown timers and I save the start timer and the remaining ms in a timer object. The thing is that the timer seems to work Ok while the activity is not on top. I'm using a partial wake lock while timers are running.

Comment: Well, for a countdown timer you should use an alarm to take action when for the time of completion. Look up AlarmManager. Your activity should just pick up the start time from sharedpreferences of the timer and display the difference to current time in the UI. This will work for all phones regardless of what the user does.

Comment: Looking into this. But the alarm itself isnt even the problem. After the new Activity opens the countdown is still running, just not visible in the activity but the alarm goes off. I have to be able to use multiple countdowns at the same time and pause/resume them. So if I understand the AlarmManager correct I still need to use a Countdown to resume the alarm after it was paused. If nothing else works I probably have to stop every countdown, write the TimerObjects to a file and read them onStart.

Comment: Yes, you should be writing your multiple timers to persistent storage, probably sqlite/contentprovider. With your alarmmanager set up, just set up the alarm for the soonest expiring timer, once that goes off, set the alarm again for the next soonest.

Comment: Is it a problem (performance wise) to write the Timer Objects to a file instead of the variables of the Objects to create a new Object with the saved variables? Im doing this with a ListView I use and it seems to work ok. Just seems to be overkill so setup a sql db for a few timers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That would be acceptable. Just that flat file writing can be more painful depending on what you are used to. Personally I would use sqlite and content provider, it helps remove any race conditions or potential corruption.